# Display images from private files to public

Tags: 8, media

Is it possible to display private files/images to the public for example with tiwg tweak?

I've tried examples from here: https://www.specbee.com/blogs/twig-tweak-in-drupal-9-functions-and-filters which was the best I could find relating to my issue.

In the article from above I found:

```
{{ drupal_field(field_name, entity_type, id, view_mode, language,access_check) }}
```

And this is the code I used, which didn't throw an error but gave me results neither:

```
{{ drupal_field('field_event_image', 'node', { type: 'image_url', settings: { image_style: 'medium'} }, check_access=false) }}
```

The relevant thing should be the access check, but maybe it's just me and I don't know how to use it right.

Comment: Do you have special permissions hiding the private files?  Usually, private files are served through the *private* file system, but they are not hidden from the public.

Comment: Note that `check_access=false` is related to the parent node no to the referenced file.